# Why we can get the whole DOM of parent component when child component's mounted hook is just triggered?

Tags: vue.js, components, vue-component

Just start learning vue days ago, and one question confused me a few days. As the code below:

```html
// inside the parent.vue
<div>
    <child-component-a />
    <child-component-a />
    <div>hello</div>
</div>
...
```

```html
// inside the child-component-a.vue
<div>child a</div>
...
```

```html
// inside the child-component-b.vue
<div>child b</div>
...
```

In my view, when the child components' `mounted` hooks is triggered, the `dom` should not be available, below is my thought:

```js
// inside the child-component-a.vue
export default {
    ...,
    mounted() {
        // here the DOM is "<div><div>child a</div></div>"
        // and not inserted into document yet 
    }
}
```

```js
// inside the child-component-b.vue
export default {
    ...,
    mounted() {
        // here the DOM is "<div><div>child a</div><div>child-b</div></div>"
        // and also not inserted
    }
}
```

```js
// inside the parent.vue
export default {
    ...,
    mounted() {
        // here the DOM is "<div><div>child a</div><div>child b</div><div>hello</div></div>"
        // and the whole dom has been inserted into document
        // so we can manipulate the html element with document APIs
    }
}
```

But, actually we can get the whole DOM by document API just when child-a's mounted hook is triggered, why?

Answer (score 1):

Vue.js builds its virtual DOM synchronously before inserting it into the HTML. In order to build an element, it needs to build the child elements as well. It does this in a pre-order, depth-first manner, much like the way the browser builds normal HTML (see https://dom.spec.whatwg.org#trees). I.e, In order to display the top-level `div`, it needs to know what `child-component-a` and `child-component-b` are first. Here is the render order:

1. `div` we see a div component that has children. We need to render them first so we know how to draw this element on the screen.
2. `a` doesn't have any child components to render, so we render the `a` element.
3. `b` has no children, so we render `b`. (note that `a` has already been rendered)
4. `div` ("hello") has no child nodes, so we render its contents (`a` and `b` have both been rendered)
5. `div` (top-level) Now that all the subcomponents have been rendered and we know how to draw them, we can render the parent node.
6. [ Vues.js: Compare this tree with the existing DOM, and only update the elements that need it. ]

NOTE: this is slightly simplified. text contents are `text` nodes, and they are rendered accordingly.

On a personal note, I think if you are going to use a toolkit like Vue, you should leverage its API whenever possible, instead of attempting to use low-level APIs when you don't need them. I honestly don't understand why you would need to use this in any real-world scenario, other than just exploring how Vue works. If you are exploring, Kudos to you! [Vue's API documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/) and [Guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/) are pretty verbose, and I recommend sitting down and reading them in their entirety. For things you get stuck on, the [W3C standards documentation](https://www.w3.org/standards/) ([especially on the DOM](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org#trees) and [WhatWG](https://whatwg.org)) is quite amazing as well, although it is quite a bit more technical. You don't have to commit to memory all the information therein, just read it and I am sure it will come back when you need it.

Comment: I think maybe I do not express clearly, what I wanna know is when exactly the `mounted` hook is triggered? I think the whole virtual DOM should be generated before its rendered in the browser, and when the render starts, the parent container `div` will be first rendered in browser, and then the html of each `child` component should be inserted into the container `div` one by one, so when the `child-a`'s `mounted` hook  is triggered, the `html` in browser should be `<div><div>child a</div></div>`... then `child-b`..., and when all `html` rendered, the `parent`'s `mounted` hook is triggered.

Comment: I don't think vue renders this way. There is a lifecycle diagram in the docs: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/instance.html#lifecycle-diagram if that is what you are looking for. If you are asking why the local context is different from the rendered context, you should read about the virtual DOM. There is a good deep dive here: https://medium.com/@koheimikami/understanding-rendering-process-with-virtual-dom-in-vue-js-a6e602811782